# Why there are so much issues with realtek wireless chips?

Tags: wireless

Often, on Ask Ubuntu, questions are about wireless issue of realtek chips on Ubuntu. Why? I will edit my ask to add examples topics in needed.

Answer (score 2):

Lack of support for linux is the main issue. And it is a downwards spiral: we know it does not work without tinkering every install, so we do not buy hardware with it when a competitor nic does work, so we get ignored by that company.

Next issue is licenses. Parts of the software for the nic might be proprietairy. And that means we can not have it included in the install. And a post install of a nic driver is troublesome when you need driver to work to download the driver.

The 3rd issue will be the ability to tinker with the system. My mother uses Ubuntu and has zero affinity with coding. But she did buy a system and told me regardless of the brand of the NIC to install Ubuntu. Of course it was not Intel. The 1st time it took me days (mainly asking @chili555 in AU chat ;) ) but I learned a lot from it. Nowadays I go: meh, annoying but I will get it done.

So ....Intel nic almost always work out of the box.  I always ask what is inside a notebook before purchasing and always opt for intel when i can. I can get realtek to work but I got better things to do ;)

Comment: I'm also Intel when it comes to Linux. Intel is one of the key developers of Linux so it makes sense their drivers work "out-of-the-box".

Comment: Think it is more of a 'picnic' issue, problem in company, not in computer.  Also think maybe 'ask ubuntu' should have a chat tag/section for questions like this.